# What happpens to /etc/passwd- file when useradd command fails

Tags: linux, user-accounts

I know that when a user is added using the `useradd` command, it creates a backup of `/etc/passwd` in `/etc/passwd-`, and then add the new user into the `/etc/passwd`. Suppose if by some chance the `useradd` command fails to add new user to `/etc/passwd` file, will the content of `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/passwd-` file be same or will the `/etc/passwd-` file be rolled back to the original content before adding the new user?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid the only way to be *sure* about the answer, here, is to look at the source.  Because, even if you could find a way to cause it to fail, different failures might incur different actions.  That being said, the most logical course of action would be simple: use the extant /etc/passwd file.  If it hasn't made the change, no problem; if it has, it's committed.  It's pretty close to atomic.